# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError after enabling progaurd

Tags: android

```html
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/app.trell-cObHRbb2g2I_GJO51h1Usw==/lib/arm64/libNvStreamingSdkCore.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1071)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
        at com.meicam.sdk.NvsStreamingContext.C(NvsStreamingContext.java:16)
        at com.meishe.sdkdemo.MSApplication.init(MSApplication.java:4)
        at com.meishe.sdkdemo.MSAppLoaderImpl.initMSApplication(MSAppLoader.kt:1)
        at app.geochat.revamp.utils.Utils.b0(Utils.java:3)
        at app.geochat.revamp.activity.HomeGenericActivity.Y0(HomeGenericActivity.java:24)
        at app.geochat.revamp.activity.HomeGenericActivity.onClick(HomeGenericActivity.java:223)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7254)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7212)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:828)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27889)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
```

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad  after enabling progaurd

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude a class from proguard. One of the lib. you're using rely on a C++ library and it's getting swallowed by proguard